# Help with lights flickering at weird regular interval

Tags: electrical, lighting

Lights flicker for ~17 seconds at 1 flash/sec, then normal for ~23 seconds. This cycle repeats itself continuously.

The video starts with the 23 second "normal" period, followed by 17 seconds of flickering, and shows 2 cycles. May need to turn screen brightness up, but if you watch closely the flashes are evident.

Context about my home's electrical system:

- video is of ceiling light
- flickering is not isolated to a single circuit. Occurs in bedroom
  circuit, bathroom circuit, kitchen circuit (fridge light),
  outside garage light, and floor lamps plugged into outlets
- 1950's house, copper wiring, no ground on most circuits except for
  kitchen. Location is in Indiana, USA
- In Jan 2018, recently after purchasing house, I:

  - installed GFCI outlets at the head of each circuit to conform with NEC code for having 3-prong (grounded) outlets on wiring with no ground.
  - replaced all other normal receptacles and switches
  - replaced all lights with LEDs
  - flickering phenomenon only started about 4 months ago, well after I made above changes
- I have a single dimmer switch for kitchen ceiling light, which is LED. Both dimmer switch and LED claim compatibility with dimming functionality. Oddly enough, this light doesn't flicker, at least not strongly enough that I can perceive it
- 100 amp service

Things I've tried already:

- Had utility company replace connections to weather-head due to
  imbalance on legs of main coming into panel. Flickering was occurring
  before this, and this did not solve.
- Asked utility company if transformer was sized appropriately/working correctly. Technician said yes, but also didn't climb pole to inspect transformer.
- Inspected breakers on all circuits. Replaced some that I thought
  could have poor connection, but flickering continued.
- Inspected panel for any loose connections at bus bar, tightened a few, but found nothing suspect

I'm fairly handy, an engineer, and confident in my ability to troubleshoot without getting myself electrocuted, but I'm out of ideas. Any thoughts?

[Link to video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!Aia_9M4x9EN59TXBreloCSOKkReB)

Panel model info: [image: Panel Model Pic 1][image: Panel Model Pic 2] [image: Panel Model Pic 3]

Comment: Cool!  The regularity of it is interesting.

Comment: Also, do you have any smart devices connected?  and CFLs?  what else might have a timer in it?

Comment: I have smart devices as in a Google Home. No smart lighting devices though. Everything is LED, no CFLs. Nothing I can think of that would have a timer.

Comment: Ok - I had similar problems with CFLs, and it could be a poorly designed AC-DC converter in your LEDs,  but it seems more likely to be related to a device that is 'calling home'  - do you have solar?

Comment: What make and model is the main panel in the house, and are all the circuits on the same leg of the panel/service?

Comment: Pull the dimmer out, and do [this Dictaphone treatment](https://youtu.be/Wf8Vl0ORBaE?t=43s)...  Seriously, dimmers, lighted switches, motion sensors, X10, smart switches and any other powered-switch devices have *absolutely no place* in a house where you are trying to troubleshoot a problem like this... they will always cast a shadow of doubt, and can "come back" when the problem is fixed.

Comment: No solar. Panel: Underwriter Laboratories / Class CTL No. FG 099103, LC41 BOX3503.

Comment: @nbdyowens -- can you get us photos of the labeling on the panel (look at the inside of the door, usually)? The information you're providing isn't actually very useful

Comment: Thought that might be the case. I've added to original post.

Comment: Does the flickering change when you start up a heavy amp load, like a 220v dryer or your whole-house A/C?  It sounds like your move to LEDs may have dropped your house's load well below the old norm.  Maybe a heavy load will overwhelm the low-load 'capacitor' in your service that you've uncovered.  If it doesn't affect ALL your circuits, maybe it's a poor ground on one of the panel's two ground bars?.  (Can you check the temp of the panel with a IR sensor gun to see if a ground bar has heated up?)

Comment: The periodic flickering described doesn't change on an appliance start up. It may get a tiny bit worse (flicker is tiny bit more noticeable), but not much. Conversely, when a big load (fan, well pump, dryer) does start I do experience a single deep flicker, but not really too worried about that. It's happened since I purchased. Flickering does affect all circuits. Measured ground bar temp = 78 (house is 76).

Comment: @nbdyowens -- can you step back a bit and give us clear photos of the panel as a whole?

Comment: What is the make of the LED lights?  A few years ago I bought a bunch of generic bioluz lights which claimed to be dimmable and LED dimming switch.  They flickered occasionally, followed by regularly, and eventually one of the drivers overheated and started sparking.  I only use more reputable LED brands now and don't have that issue.

Comment: @nbdyowens I have virtually the same issue! Did you get this resolved? I note too that when I flip a certain breaker the issue is resolved for about 24 hours too. Please help :)

Comment: Did you measure the voltages in your system? Between neutral and phase, but also neutral to ground and phase to ground?

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue?  I have the same issue; lights pulse every second for 17 seconds then stop for 20 seconds, then repeat. I have noticed the flickering happens across the entire house both for LED and nonLED bulbs (although almost all bulbs are LED). Also most LED bulbs are Nanoleaf essential smart bulbs running on a fairly extensive Apple homekit setup.

Answer (score 3):

I had strange flickering in the past (but not quite with the strange periodicity you are), and this is how I found the device(s) that was dirtying up the power for my whole house:

1. Go to the breaker and shutoff all but one of the flickering circuits

Did the flickering stop?

**if yes**:

2. One by one turn each circuit back on until the flickering returns
3. Once flicking returns you now know which circuit contains the device causing the problem (the last one you turned on). One by one, unplug/unscrew each device/bulb from the circuit until the flickering stops

**if no:**

- Turn off the circuit, and switch on a different one that you had noticed flickering on

  - If the flickering is gone, it was due to a device in your home, proceed to step 3 to isolate the device.
  - If you are still experiencing flickering, it is likely due to a problem your electrical carriers equipment.  Call them and let them know you've isolated the problem to something on their end.

Comment: In doing process you described, have confirmed another symptom, which is making it especially difficult to actually troubleshoot. When I flip any breaker, flickering stops, for a time. But then gradually, over 25-48 hours, it comes back, so I haven't been able to identify which circuit is culprit. Seems like it could be related to some weird capacitance phenomenon. My next idea was to do same process you described, but with devices plugged into receptacles. This wasn't successful either, as I've basically unplugged everything I can (short of disconnecting each light fixture).

Comment: The LED lighting should be the first things you check as they are the most likely devices to have some sort of advanced electronic circuit done as cheaply as possible

Answer (score 2):

It's the toaster oven cycling.   My Breville does that, whole house has LED bulbs that only flicker when oven is on.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem it turned out to be the preheater in my ninja coffee maker. Now i turn the coffee maker off till im ready to use it. Problem Solved.

Comment: My problem was the Keurig coffee maker heating element coming on as it’s always pre-heating.

Comment: Just figured out my problem was a Ninja Coffee Maker as well! It explains the on off nature of the pulse. Heat up to a temp and then turn off till it drops back down (about 17-20 seconds on -> creates a one second pulse then off for about 17-20 seconds -> no pulse)

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem, it seems that power fluctuations can be common. This can be caused by a central heating system turning on or off, or an oven or something else. Unfortunately with LED bulbs in particular they are incredibly sensitive to slight variations in power / voltages.

If this isn't a wiring problem and the flickering is once every minute or so - like mine, just swap the LED bulb for a dimmable LED bulb.

In my case I am suspicious that it's something going on with the meter.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//diy.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.